# Running DB Functions as other users

Tags: security, roles, greenplum

I feel rather silly for asking this question as I feel it spits right in the face of all security principles. Alas, here is my question. I am curious if it's even possible to essentially 'run on behalf of' various user accounts within Greenplum Databases without being provided their credentials. The reason I ask is I have a functional account and would like to execute things such as DB procedures, functions, etc on behalf of the requestors username. This is to ensure we're not running procedures that they themselves don't have acccess to run, or one that access datasets that they themselves don't have access to.

Again, feeling silly for this one, but if this is possible, it would solve a pretty large issue I'm encountering :D

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed provisions for this behavior :

`SECURITY INVOKER indicates that the function is to be executed with the privileges of the user that calls it. That is the default. SECURITY DEFINER specifies that the function is to be executed with the privileges of the user that created it.`

See here : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: Interesting. So I also found this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-set-role.html .  Is this feasible as well?

Comment: And this (if it were set to SECURITY DEFINER) would imply literally anyone could run the function and get it to run, correct? Assuming the creator of said function didn't remove their own access....right?

Comment: SECURITY DEFINER runs the function as the user who owns the function (despite the term "DEFINER" you can still change the ownership of a function and this user is used to run it). You can also use GRANT and REVOKE to define who is allowed to run this function. If you grant the permission to PUBLIC; everybody can run it.

Comment: Oh and keep in mind: if this function is doing something secretly (like a task which requires passwords), every user might still be able to see the function definition and extract the passwords. Even when the user can not run the function.

Comment: So I guess would the SET ROLE route be a more viable/secure method?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do exactly. SET ROLE requires a user to actually become the "proxy user", whereas, security definer allows the user defining the function to delegate "do-as" / impersonation on a function by function basis. In my opinion, it's perfectly viable and secure as long as you don't expose secrets in your code body, which shouldn't store that information anyway.